# limit exist or not

Tags: limits

[image]

I am confused with statement B . I think it is correct as limit exist when x approaches to 1 as statement A .

But in mybook it it given statement B is wrong .

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What about taking $g(x) = 2x/3$?

Comment: $B$ is not correct. Suppose $g(x)=|x-1|$. The right hand and left hand limits in option $B$ aren't equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the limit may exist or not, depending on the function $g$.

Suppose you have a continuous function $g$ such that $g(1)=\dfrac{2N}3\;(N\in\mathbf N)$, such that in every neighbourhood of $1$, there exists values of $x$ with $g(x)<g(1)$ as well as $g(x)>1$.

Then $\biggr[\dfrac{3g(1)}2\biggr]=N$, and, if $x$ is near enough to $1$,
$$\biggr[\frac{3g(x)}2\biggr]=\begin{cases}N&\text{if }g(x)>g(1),\\ N-1&\text{if }g(x)<g(1).\end{cases}.$$
You may take, for instance,
$$g(x)=\frac{2N}3+(x-1)\sin\frac1{x-1}.$$